# web3.personal.newAccount how to get address

Tags: web3js, accounts

If I do `web3.personal.newAccount("passphrase")` from my code then how can I get back the address that was created using my passphrase? 
Moreover can anyone tell me the difference of `web3.personal.newAccount` & web3.eth.accounts.create both are creating accounts and if by second method i store the key in keystore then how can I unlock the account using `web3.personal.unlockAccount` ?

Answer (score 3):

> Moreover can anyone tell me the difference of web3.personal.newAccount & web3.eth.accounts.create both are creating accounts and if by second method i store the key in keystore then how can I unlock the account using web3.personal.unlockAccount?

The big difference is:

1. `web3.personal.newAccount` is used to **generate addresses on the wallet associated with your node/provider. This is misleading as `personal` method is not necessarily local.** Do not use this method unless you are running your own node (i.e. Geth or Parity). If you are using Infura or similar provider service, I doubt you'd want to create a wallet account on their node.
2. `web3.eth.accounts.create` will **generate a local key pair**. If you use this method, definitely make sure to store your key info, as it is only kept TEMPORARY in memory. You can then send transactions with `web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey)`, but you have to encode any contract data with an encodeABI method first before placing it in `tx`. This is not a recommended method, and this approach is used under the hood by browser-based wallet providers like Metamask.

To query the list of accounts controlled by your node wallet use `web3.eth.getAccounts()`. I need to look into how you can get a list of locally generated addresses.

Answer (score 1):

> If I do web3.personal.newAccount("passphrase") from my code then how can I get back the address that was created using my passphrase?

`addr = w3.personal.newAccount("passphrase")`

> Moreover can anyone tell me the difference of `web3.personal.newAccount` & `web3.eth.accounts.create` both are creating accounts and if by second method i store the key in keystore then how can I unlock the account using `web3.personal.unlockAccount`?

Sorry, can't help you with that - but FWIW I couldn't make `web3.eth.accounts.create` work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of accounts created through `web3.eth.accounts`, listed in chronological order of creation.

Comment: But it at that time may be some other already created a one then? Is there no way to get the address back?

Comment: Sidharthat's question is about `web3.personal`, i.e. local accounts.